# To detect objects (hyperbolas) in a pre-processed image (image processing in matlab)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, textures, feature-extraction, object-detection

I would really appreciate help with regards to what approach/ method to adopt for my problem.

I have grey scale images (as shown in the top left image of pic below)

screenshot:

[image]

On this I have done some pre-processing to clearly identify its details. I would like to detect  (as boxes) all the hyperbolas/ hyperbolic curvature contained (as marked by red boxes as examples) in such pre-processed images based on shape and (higher) intensity and remove the remaining noise.

I shall really appreciate any help as to how to proceed in dealing with it.

Comment: Interesting problem. Anyway, can you give more details about what you have done? What pre-processing did you do? How did you arrive at the red boxes? Why do the four images look all different? How much variability is expected between your data?

Comment: How do you know that these are hyperbolas ?

Comment: Do you need to detect in the four types of images ??? The right box in the top right image is nonsense.

Comment: @YvesDaoust those are hyperbolas for sure as these are GPR profiles (the samples) and they contain hyperbolic signatures known from literature. I need to detect in the three images (except the top left as it is non-processed) ..and yes some are not very clear like in the right box in the top right image but any approach to identify such curvatures is needed

Comment: You should consider template matching by NGC, which will be pretty discriminant.

Comment: "identify such curvatures": no, the right box in the top right image shows no curvature. And what you have in this whole row is just an unmanageable mess, not even achievable by a human.

Comment: @YvesDaoust what is NGC please? N is there any approach besides template matching you could think of.. coz template matching would require lots of training samples.any approch which would identify based on the characteristics/ shape/ texture of the hyperbola

Comment: What makes you think that lots of training samples are required ? What's the variability of your problem ?

Comment: Between us, looks weird to me that you want to work with those ugly preprocessed images. Are you trying to assess a detection method automatically ?

Comment: Try normalized grayscale correlation.

Comment: Are you trying to implement the Amsterdam shroud?

Comment: @AnderBiguri well its not ..these are images of construction bridges but it does look similar to amsterdam shroud..thanks ..will see if approaches for that works for me

Comment: Any other  better approaches for detecting shape and object suggestions would be appreciated